# "... logged-in ..." seems top of my website

Tags: debug

I dont know what is these mean so can you explain to fix it:

```
class="home page-template-default page page-id-50 logged-in theme-html5blank-stable woocommerce-no-js ehf-header ehf-footer ehf-template-html5blank-stable ehf-stylesheet-html5blank-stable elementor-default elementor-kit-1715 elementor-page elementor-page-50"
```

here is my website link:

http://www.migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/

Thank you

Comment: That's a class WordPress adds to the <body> tag if you're logged-in to the site. And check your `header.php` or check the `<body>` tag there. It could also be a filter/function that causing the classes to be put outside the tag.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks I solved and editted question with solution

Comment: Ok, but it's a better option to roll back your edit and instead, write an answer - and accept it (later). That would add the "green" indicator/button to your question in search results and will let people know the question has an accepted solution. Alternatively, set the question title to `[SOLVED] <title>`.

Comment: Ok I did so I will wait two days to be correct my answer

Comment: Great and I hope you don't mind I edited the answer... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's Used to All class add to wordpress body element Using *body_class();* function.

Specifically, it's used to adding body classes, removing body classes, conditionally adding body classes and some use cases.

> **The Body Class: What Can It Be Used For?**

The body class in WordPress is a class or series of classes that are applied to the HTML body element. This is useful for applying unique styles to different areas of a WordPress site as body classes can be added conditionally.

- This is a really simple way to add body classes and is especially useful if you are creating a theme, using this below code is header.php body element

> < body `<?php body_class();` ?> >

**Adding Multiple Body Classes**

There may be times when you want to add more than one body class. This can be achieved using a simple

> `< body <?php body_class( array( "class-one", "class-two", "class-three" ) ); ?>>`

**Conditionally Adding a Body Class**

This example uses the WooCommerce conditional method of is_shop() :

```
<?php if ( is_shop() ) { body_class( 'is-woocommerce-shop' ); } else { body_class(); } ?>
```

**Adding a Body Class by Filter**

It's possible to use a WordPress filter to add a body class, This code can either go in your themes functions.php or within your plugin.

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {

    $classes[] = 'your-custom-class-name';

    return $classes;

}
```

[refer Link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-to-the-body-class-in-wordpress--cms-21077) For More Knowledge

Answer (score 2):

Those are the classes echoed by [`body_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) and the problem was, I called the function outside of the `<body>` tag:

```
<body>
    <?php body_class(); ?>
```

So I changed that to:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

And that solved the problem. :)